# Unexpected characters in reading data from socket to byte array

Tags: java, c++, network-programming, kafka-consumer-api

I get data from **UDP** port using **c++** programming. Suppose we receive socket data to `char buf[2000]`. When I print data (converted to Hex code) there are some unexpected data in messages. For example, running the code:

```
for (int i =0 ; i < 2000; i++) 
{ 
  printf(" "); 
  printf("%02x", buf[i]); 
}
```

the output is:

`EF BF BD 01 00 1C 1E 39 5A 18 40 EF BF BD 00 38 51 EF BF BD 00 00 EF BF BD EF BF BD 00 48 00 EF BF BD 00 00 00 64 EF BF BD 1F`

the `EF BF BD` pattern in code is unexpected and extra.
For solving this issue I convert `char` to `unsigned char` and using the code :

```
for (int i =0 ; i < 2000; i++) 
{ 
  printf(" "); 
  printf("%02x", (unsighed char)buf[i]); 
}
```

Now the output is containing the desired result:

`aa 01 00 1c 1e 39 5a 18 50 fc 00 61 47 ae 00 00 ff b6 00 4e 01 f4 00 00 00 64 b5 4f`

(Please note outputs are for different messages)

After that, I write messages to Kafka. The problem is when I read messages from Kafka, **this time using Java programming** using the following codes:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
byte[] temp = record.value().getBytes();
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (byte b : temp) {
        result.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        result.append(" "); // delimiter
                    }
System.out.println(result);
```

and the output is :

`EF BF BD 01 00 1C 1E 39 5A 18 40 EF BF BD 00 38 51 EF BF BD 00 00 EF BF BD EF BF BD 00 48 00 EF BF BD 00 00 00 64 EF BF BD 1F`

again with extra `EF BF BD` undesired pattern.

So the **main question** is how can I changes the **java code** to print messages in the correct way, just exactly like what I did in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be reading bytes which use a one-byte charset to represent text (like ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252), but you are choosing to read them using library functions which assume those bytes are a UTF-8 representation of text.

‘aa’ is not a valid starting byte for a UTF-8 representation of a character.  Whatever mechanism you’re using to convert bytes to characters knows this, and inserts `�`, the [Unicode replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), as an indication of invalid input.

The UTF-8 representation of `�` is the three bytes ‘ef bf bd’.

Always specify the correct charset when converting between bytes and characters.  This is not a problem in the code you’ve shown in your question;  rather, it is a problem with the code that read bytes and converted them to the String value that is `record.value()`.  It is that code which interpreted the ‘aa’ byte as a malformed UTF-8 sequence and put `�` in your string to indicate the problem.

That code, if it’s in Java, probably used `new String(bytes)`.  It should have used `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)` (or possibly `new String(bytes, "windows-1252")` or some other one-byte charset).

When you convert a String back to bytes, the same rules apply.  If you want an `ª` character to be decoded into the single byte ‘aa’, you need to use a one-byte encoding:

```
record.value().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

As I said, though, currently record.value() does not start with `ª`, it starts with `�`. record.value().getBytes() uses your system’s default charset (UTF-8), so the first three bytes of the returned array are the UTF-8 representation of `�`, which is ‘ef bf bd’.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! I tried `ISO_8859_1` and `windows-1252` but in both, `aa` is changed to `3f` like the following: `3F  01  00  1C  1E  39  5A  18  40  3F  00  38  51  3F  00  00  3F  3F  00  48  00  3F  00  00  00  64  3F  1F`

Comment: ‘3f’ is the question mark (`?`), which is the one-byte equivalent of `�`.  Now that I look more closely at your data, I have to wonder why you’re trying to convert it to and from a String at all, since you have plenty of bytes which obviously are not text.  You should avoid using Strings, and just use byte arrays instead.  In Java, unlike in C, a char and a byte are not the same thing.